# how to trouble shoot CakePHP email component errors in Sign Me Up plugin

Tags: email, cakephp, components

I'm using the Sign Me Up plugin from [Jotlab](http://www.jotlab.com/2011/01/29/sign-me-up-a-cakephp-registration-plugin/) and am having problems with sending emails. I've tried to contact the author but no luck so far.

I'm using this with an ACL plugin and everything but sending emails is working so far. All research and trouble shooting hasn't resulted in any answers.

This is a cakephp 2.x version, and I'm aware that the email component is deprecated but should work.

When I submit the registration form, the record does get inserted but the email isn't sent and I get this error message.

```
#0 C:\wamp\www\blue2\lib\Cake\Network\Email\CakeEmail.php(967): MailTransport->send(Object(CakeEmail))
#1 C:\wamp\www\blue2\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\EmailComponent.php(345): CakeEmail->send(Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\blue2\app\Plugin\sign_me_up\Controller\Component\SignMeUpComponent.php(143): EmailComponent->send(Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\blue2\app\Plugin\sign_me_up\Controller\Component\SignMeUpComponent.php(103): SignMeUpComponent->__sendActivationEmail(Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\blue2\app\Plugin\AclManagement\Controller\UsersController.php(57): SignMeUpComponent->register()
#5 [internal function]: UsersController->register()
#6 C:\wamp\www\blue2\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php(473): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(UsersController), Array)
#7 C:\wamp\www\blue2\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(104): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#8 C:\wamp\www\blue2\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(86): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(UsersController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#9 C:\wamp\www\blue2\app\webroot\index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#10 {main}
```

Here is the code that's in the controller for the register function:

```
public function register() {
    $this->__isLoggedIn();
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        extract($this->settings);
        $model = $this->controller->modelClass;
        $this->controller->loadModel($model);
        $this->controller->{$model}->set($this->data);

        if (CakePlugin::loaded('Mongodb')) {
            $this->controller->{$model}->Behaviors->attach('Mongodb.SqlCompatible');
        }

        if ($this->controller->{$model}->validates()) {
            if (!empty($activation_field)) {
                $this->data[$model][$activation_field] = $this->controller->{$model}->generateActivationCode($this->data);
            } elseif (!empty($useractive_field)) {
                $this->data[$model][$useractive_field] = true;
            }

            if ($this->controller->{$model}->save($this->data, false)) {
                //If an activation field is supplied send out an email
                if (!empty($activation_field)) {
                    $this->__sendActivationEmail($this->data[$model]);
                    if (!$this->controller->request->is('ajax')) {
                        $this->controller->redirect(array('action' => 'activate'));
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->__sendWelcomeEmail($this->data[$model]);
                }
                if (!$this->controller->request->is('ajax')) {
                    $this->controller->redirect($this->Auth->loginAction);
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The 'send activation email' and 'send welcome email' are as follows:

```
protected function __sendActivationEmail($userData) {
    $this->__setUpEmailParams($userData);
    $this->__parseEmailSubject('activation', $userData);
    if ($this->__setTemplate(Configure::read('SignMeUp.activation_template'))) {
        if ($this->Email->send($userData)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

protected function __sendWelcomeEmail($userData) {
    $this->__setUpEmailParams($userData);
    $this->__parseEmailSubject('welcome', $userData);
    if ($this->__setTemplate(Configure::read('SignMeUp.welcome_template'))) {
        if ($this->Email->send($userData)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I've read the cake documentation on emails and have tried a number of things including re-installing more than once.

Any help on how to trouble shoot these error message is much appreciated.

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 0):

The missing file has been found. For some reason my 'default.ctp' file in view/emails/text was missing. Also ensure that it's got the following code in it:

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

Emails work fine now.